# Тип сказуемого

Tags: сказуемые, синтаксис

> С этого дня принц женихом стал ездить
> во дворец.

Это предложение дали для разбора в вузе. Задание: охарактеризовать сказуемое, выделив его в тексте. Студентка определила неверно и пришла за объяснением. Хочу поделиться интересным заданием с любителями словесности.

Как бы вы охарактеризовали сказуемое и где здесь оно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вариант 1. Сказуемое - стал ездить женихом,  осложненное составное именное сказуемое.

Глагольная часть состоит из фазового глагола "стал" и знаменательной связки именного сказуемого "ездить" со значением движения. Такой разбор приводится у Розенталя.

Вариант 2. Сказуемое - стал ездить (составное глагольное), женихом - дуплексив с двунаправленной связью, относится к подлежащему и сказуемому (обстоятельственное определение, выраженное падежной формой существительного). Это сведения из современной грамматики.

Причиной такого неоднозначного решения является то, что  знаменательная связка "ездить" выражает полноценный предикативный признак, и тогда сказуемые данного типа могут рассматриваться как сочетание  глагольного сказуемого с дуплексивом (обычный пример дуплексива: он вернулся расстроенным, она вернулась расстроенной).

Comment: Браво!!! Совершенно верно. Это сложное сказуемое - СГС + СИС . В этом примере глагол "стать" используется в двух  качествах: фазисный вспомогательный глагол в СГС и полуотвлеченная связка в осложнённом СИС. Но сказуемое (как требовалось)однозначно"стал ездить женихом", потому что дуплексив "женихом"в обоих вариантах выражает главное сообщение о действии субъекта.В школе, конечно, таких примеров нет.

Comment: А в "Ягнёнок пришёл к ручью напиться" – сказуемое "пришёл"?

Comment: пришёл - сказуемое, зачем? - напиться - обстоятельство цели.

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить: "стал ездить женихом". Если уж задание интересное и студентка определила неверно. )))

СИС.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно такие примеры рассматриваются как осложненное именное сказуемое. Вера, а кто автор этой современной грамматики?

Comment: Это вузовский учебник Г.И. Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка. Курс лекций". Там говорится о том, что дуплексивы (он пришел усталый) обычно входят в состав именного сказуемого (основной вариант), но иногда могут рассматриваться как сочетание простого глагольного сказуемого с предикативным определением.